# How to have equal space between text in Python?

Tags: python, string, tkinter

How do I format my text to have equal spaces between them despite varying text lengths inside my Listbox in tkinter? What happens is that the itemPrice values don't align with each other correctly[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCFgR.png).
My current code is

```
menu_list = open("items.txt", "r")
for item in menu_list:
    data = item.split(':')
    itemDescription = data[0]
    itemPrice =data[1]
    item =  f'{itemDescription: <40}{itemPrice}'
    item_list.insert(END, item)
menu_list.close
```

[items.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Nfv.png)
[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCFgR.png)

Comment: Use fixed width (monospaced) font.  Also `menu_list.close` should be `menu_list.close()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `\t` characters in your strings.

```py
    item =  f'{itemDescription: <40}\t\t\t{itemPrice}'
```

These are tabs, by the way. They are pretty useful in aligning text.